# how does an EAR file's lib directory get used?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, ear

I've used EAR files for some time now and I've never put anything in it's LIB directory. How does that work anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put JAR files in the EAR lib directory and these JAR files will then be available to all the modules packed in the EAR. So you typically put libraries in their that you need across all your modules.